# Checking if a class contains any properties of type double and converting them to integers

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a fairly complex model class that I need to compare to another class of the same type. I've already implemented a compare function using reflection, but one of the classes will have values rounded to the integer, and the other will have values as doubles. I need to round all of those double values to the nearest integer, in order for my comparison function to work.

The Compare function in question:

```
public static List<Variance> DetailedCompare<Type>(this Type saveModel, Type loadModel)
{

    List<Variance> variancesList = new List<Variance>();
    PropertyInfo[] fieldList = saveModel.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo field in fieldList)
    {
        if (!ignoreList.Contains(field.Name))
        {
            Variance variance = new Variance();
            variance.property = field.Name;
            variance.saveValue = field.GetValue(saveModel, null);
            variance.loadValue = field.GetValue(loadModel, null);

            if (!Equals(variance.saveValue, variance.loadValue))
                variancesList.Add(variance);
        }
    }
    return variancesList;
}
```

The model class I need to compare:

```
public class DisplayModel
{
    public Point topLeft { get; set; }
    public Point bottomRight { get; set; }
    public double? intercept { get; set; }
}

public class Point
{
    public double x { get; set; }
    public double y { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way to iterate through the object properties and check if they're of type double, or would changing each one manually be necessary?

Edit: To be a bit more specific, I'm mostly having trouble with the nested complex types. Checking variables like intercept aren't too bad, but I'm not sure what's the best way to deal with things like topLeft and bottomRight. There are also complex types like Point, but with a different property name, so ideally I'd rather not check for a Point object directly.

Comment: You can get the list of properties through reflection and then can use `GetType()` method to check if it's of double.

Comment: You're looking to get the properties of the nested complex types too, right?

Comment: Sorry about the delay in responding, but I am looking for the properties of the nested types.

Answer (score 1):

you can use PropertyType:

```
if (field.PropertyType == typeof(double))
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.propertytype(v=vs.110).aspx

**Update: example**

```
class Test1{
    public int t1 {get; set;}
    public string t2  {get;  set;}
    public Type t3  {get;  set;}
    public bool t4  {get;  set;}
    public double t5  {get;  set;}
    public float t6 {get;  set;}
    public double field;
}

void Main()
{
    PrintProps(new Test1());
    PrintProps(new System.Drawing.Point());

}

private static void PrintProps(object o){
    Console.WriteLine("Begin: " + o.GetType().FullName);
    var t = o.GetType();
    var props = t.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | 
                                    BindingFlags.Instance); // you can do same with GetFields();
    foreach(var p in props){
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} = {1}", p.Name,p.PropertyType == typeof(double)));
    }   
    Console.WriteLine("End");
}
```

Sample output:

```
Begin: UserQuery+Test1
t1 = False
t2 = False
t3 = False
t4 = False
t5 = True
t6 = False
End
Begin: System.Drawing.Point
IsEmpty = False
X = False
Y = False
End
```

Comment: This might be a bit of a silly question, but how would you handle the Point class, or the double? type. I'm assuming for double?, you would have to check for that type too, but I'm stuck on how to check that if Point has any double properties, without manually checking it.

Comment: added example, hope it helps